# Catch flickity carousel click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flickity

I have a flickity.js carousel set up on my website and I want to add a couple of `mailto` links to it. Static clicks do not work in the carousel by default, so I had to use `staticClick.flickity` event to catch it:

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/zEJrLY

```
// Catch click events
$(".carousel").on("staticClick.flickity", function(event, pointer) {
    var tagName = pointer.path[0].tagName;

    if (tagName == "A") {
        var href = pointer.path[0].href;
        window.location.href = href;
        alert(href);
    }
});
```

While the `href` value is retrived OK, the `window.location.href` part doesn't work for some reason, i.e. mail client is not triggered. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open(href);` This should work. Please try this.

Comment: Thanks. It simply opened the "maito:hello@trysquad.com" page in Chrome.